# Clonezilla, timeshift and other backup issues

Tags: linux, backup, arch-linux, clonezilla

So I have been trying to make backups of my Arch Linux install. I have tried several tools in Linux as well as Clonezilla and they all have failed in one way or another. Clonezilla gives this error when I try to check if the backup is restorable. `The image of this partition is broken: nvme0n1p2` Timeshift freezes on the calculating system size right after telling it to create a backup. BackInTime seems to be working although for some reason I can’t get it to make automated backups. Idk if the backups its making is clean though, it doesn't seem to have an option for checking the backups. kup (a kde frontend to bup) was working fine, although I was only able to use it to backup user files, not the system. However, kup randomly started failing now and I don’t know why I tried removing the backup folder and letting it recreate it, but it still fails at about 80%.

I have tried running fsck on the disk and it says it's clean

Comment: This is really strange apparently, making a backup and telling it to check the image after the backup fails, but trying to restore that backup and using the option to check the image before the restore works just fine no issues.if I later go back into the clonezilla menu and select the manual image check it fails... Which is it? Is it borken or not

Comment: Might have figured out the issue with clonezilla, the issue was that I was compressing the image with zstd and that causes the issue. If I use the default gzip format I get no issues

Answer (score 0):

the issue was I was storing the backup on the root directory. if it gzip that's not a problem, but for some reason zstd compressed images fail the verification if there stored there